# Blender doesn't respond (RAM issue)

Tags: scene

I'm a Blender newbie and I have to do an animation of a project.
Shortly i have to move the camera in the scene to create a tour of my city, the problem is that the project is too heavy in terms of resources.
I have a i5-9400f , 16 Gb RAM , GTX 1050-Ti.
The scene is heavy, so heavy that the RAM is always full and often the screen freeze, because is writing to the disk (RAM is full).
Are there any solutions or all I can do is buy more RAM?

[image: Blender]
[image: Resources activity]

Comment: I'm a newbie myself so I don't know for sure if something can be done to fix this inside of Blender or not. What I do know is that I had a similar problem in 2.82 and I just decided to buy more ram and that solved my problem. Sorry, don't know why that last part didn't make it in. I'm working with 8k textures and did some research and found out that Blender can use a lot of ram depending on the operation it's performing so that it functions smoothly. Hopefully someone else can be of more help to you.

Comment: Hello :). Is your viewport in *solid/wireframe* mode or in *render preview*? That's a big difference in regards to performance.